# Find which commits didn't come from a pull request at all

Tags: github, github-issues

I'm looking to summarize all the changes we've made in a project whose repository is on GitHub over the last few months. *Most* of those changes are neatly organized into particular pull requests, and if I go to an individual commit's page, most of them will tell what branch it's from:

[image: Commit page which indicates it was merged into preview in pull request #365]

But not all! Occasionally (alas) we've pushed things directly to the main working branch (`preview`) without bundling the commit as part of a pull request.

This is trouble, because while I can readily find [all the pull requests merged over a given time period](https://github.com/hsmusic/hsmusic-wiki/pulls?q=is%3Amerged+merged%3A2023-10-25..2024-01-03), that list *won't* include any commits that snuck in outside any PR.

Any tips for how to find commits which didn't end up being linked to any particular pull request? I'm guessing a reasonable approach would be to just find all the commits which *were* included in any merged pull request, then subtract those from *all* the commits in that date range, but I don't know how to go about gathering any of that data without painstakingly copying it by hand for 30+ pull requests.